# name on y axis morris chart

Tags: label, linechart, morris.js, yaxis

I've a morris line chart and I would like to show 'population' on y-axis like this.

[image]

Comment: You can do it in HTML/CSS.

Comment: @krlzlx But How do I make that text rotate like in the example picture

Comment: Use CSS3 [transform](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)